# Page fault when running an exe with Wine

Tags: 20.04, wine

I am trying to install a BI software. I downloaded the zip file which contains the installer exe along with some DLL files. When I try to install it with wine, it crashes with the following error:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000034 in 64-bit code  
...  
System information:
    Wine build: wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
    Platform: x86_64
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.11.0-41-generic
```

Could someone please help me understand what this error is and how do I solve this?

Comment: That is a question best asked on the Wine support forums.

Comment: Wine does not support all Windows executables. Check with https://winehq.org

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s`. You might also try using Virtualbox with a Windows client for better chances of BI working.